# Difference between DragEnter and GiveFeedback

Tags: c#

I am trying out some Drag Drop functionalities and can't discern the difference between `Give Feedback` and `Drag Enter` events.

On `Drag Enter`, we check if the elements where it has entered can accept the object that is going to be dropped and show some kind of preview to the user.

Similarly, `Give Feedback` also shows the user a preview on the Drop Target if the dragged element would be dropped.

What is the difference between these two?

Similary what is the difference between `Drag Over` and `Drag Enter`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the documentation for `DragEnter` says,

> The `DragEnter` event is raised when the user first drags the mouse
>   cursor over the control during a drag-and-drop operation.
>
> The [DoDragDrop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.dodragdrop.aspx) method determines the control under the current cursor location. It then checks to see if the control is a valid drop target.
>
> If the control is a valid drop target, the `GiveFeedback` event is
>   raised with the drag-and-drop effect specified.

Hence, the difference is that `DragEnter` is raised for every control, and `GiveFeedback` is raised only for valid drop targets.

The difference between `DragEnter` and `DragOver` is that the former is raised only when the mouse enters control and the latter can be raised several times while the mouse is moved over the same control.

[Control.DragEnter Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragenter.aspx)